# Cypress BDD: Cypress Cucumber processor: Cannot Run Step Definition .js file

Tags: cypress, bdd, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, mochawesome

I am trying to build a cypress BDD framework.  I've think I've created the feature and step definition file correctly. When I run the the test with `npx cypress run --spec cypress/integration/examples/shoppingCart.feature  --headed --browser chrome`, I get the following result [here in this video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d7v8ae7ilx0eae1/shoppingCart.feature.mp4?dl=0) , the vid is about 20sec long.

I wasn't sure what to think so [I did another video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwhorpwtxxcoxfr/BDDError.mp4?dl=0) that was a process of elimination and looking at the BDD set up. I'm still unsure (this one is about 8 mins long).

I will add the feature file, step definition file and error message.

I am totally puzzled.

Error message

```
`1) End to End shopping cart
       User can purchase items and have them delivered to shipping address:
     Error: Step implementation missing for: I am on the Ecommerce page
      at Context.resolveAndRunStepDefinition (http://localhost:54824/__cypress/tests?p=cypress/integration/examples/shoppingCart.feature:12277:11)
      at Context.eval (http://localhost:54824/__cypress/tests?p=cypress/integration/examples/shoppingCart.feature:11603:35)
`
```

Feature file

Scenario: User can purchase items and have them delivered to shipping address

```
Given I am on the Ecommerce page
When I add the mobile handsets to the shopping cart
And I verify the total price of shopping cart
Then I select the checkout button
When I will select my shipping location
And I agree to the terms and conditions checkbox
When I select the Purchase button
Then I will see an alert stating my order was successful, plus an ETA delivery
```

Step Definition file

```js
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

import { Given,When,Then,And } from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps";
import Homepage from "../../../support/pageObjects/Homepage";
import orderSummaryPage from "../../../support/pageObjects/orderSummaryPage";
import completeOrderPage from "../../../support/pageObjects/completeOrderPage";
 
const homepage = new Homepage()
const StartCheckout = new orderSummaryPage()
const CompleteOrder = new completeOrderPage()
 
Given ( 'I am on the Ecommerce page', () => {
 
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('url')+"/angularpractice/")
    
    })
 
When('I add the mobile handsets to the shopping cart',function () {
 
        homepage.getShopTab().click() 
    
        this.data.mobileHandset.forEach(function(element) {// this custom commad will add items to your cart
    
              cy.AddToCart(element)  
            }); 
    
    
    StartCheckout.getBasketCheckoutButton().click()
    
    } )//end of step 
 
And('I verify the total price of shopping cart',() => {
 
    //calculate shopping cart here
    let sum=0
       
    CompleteOrder.getProductCost().each(($e1, index, $list) =>{
    
      const unitCost=$e1.text()  
      let res= unitCost.split(" ") 
      res= res[1].trim() 
      sum=Number(sum)+Number(res)
      
    }).then(function() 
    {
      cy.log(sum)
    
    })
    
    CompleteOrder.getBasketTotalCost().then(function(element)
    {
      const shopCartTotal=element.text()  
      var res= shopCartTotal.split(" ") 
      var total= res[1].trim() 
      expect(Number(total)).to.equal(sum)
    
    })
    
    
    } )//end of step
 
Then('I select the checkout button',() => {
 
    StartCheckout.getStartCheckoutButton().click()
 
} )//end of step
 
When('I will select my shipping location',() => {
 
    CompleteOrder.getShippingCountry().type('United Kingdom')
    CompleteOrder.getShippingCountryConfirm().click()
 
} )//end of step
 
And('I agree to the terms and conditions checkbox',()=> {
 
    CompleteOrder.getTermsConditionsCheckbox().click({force: true})
 
})//end of step 
 
When('I select the Purchase button',()=> {
 
    CompleteOrder.getPurchaseButton().click()
 
})
 
Then('I will see an alert stating my order was successful, plus an ETA delivery',()=> {
 
    CompleteOrder.getPurchaseAlert().then(function(element){
 
      
        const actualText= element.text()
       expect(actualText.includes('Success')).to.be.true
    
      }) 
 
})
```

I'm sure I even created the BDD framework in the right place.

[image]

Update:

I was just asked about the `non global step definitions` in my package.json  (I only copied from the 'script' section onwards).
Taking a quick look I don't even see it.

```
 "scripts": {
    "open": "cypress open",
    "scripts": "cypress run",
    "headTest": "cypress run --headed ",
    "chromeTest": "cypress run --browser chrome",
    "firefoxTest": "cypress run --browser firefox",
    "edgeTest": "cypress run --browser edge",
    "testDashboard": "cypress run --record --key 1642c226-ca7f-49c3-b513-da4ee9222ca8 --parallel",
    "clean:reports": "rm -R -f cypress/reports && mkdir cypress/reports && mkdir cypress/reports/mochareports",
    "pretest": "npm run clean:reports",
    "combine-reports": "mochawesome-merge ./cypress/reports/mocha/*.json > cypress/reports/mochareports/report.json",
    "generate-report": "marge cypress/reports/mochareports/report.json -f report -o cypress/reports/mochareports",
    "posttest": "npm run combine-reports && npm run generate-report",
    "test": "npm run scripts || npm run posttest"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true
  },
  
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^7.4.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cypress-multi-reporters": "^1.5.0",
    "mocha": "^9.0.0",
    "mochawesome": "^6.2.2",
    "mochawesome-merge": "^4.2.0",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "^5.2.0",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.12.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your `"nonGlobalStepDefinitions"` flag set to in your `cypress.json` ?

Comment: @AlapanDas  Here is is the `nonGlobalStepDefinitions`  I've added them to  my original question.   Taking a quick look,  I don't see anything that jumps out at me that indicates I have them.

Comment: I am sorry my bad, what I meant was can you check your `package.json` whether `nonGlobalStepDefinitions` is mentioned there? is it true or false ?

Comment: @AlapanDas  No problem :0) .  Let me update my question with this information

Comment: @AlapanDas  Just added the package.json information as requested.

Answer (score 3):

Add the `stepDefinitions` option to the configuration,

```
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
  "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
  "stepDefinitions": "cypress/integration/examples/BDD"
},
```

Comment: I tried it and the test still failed. However I appreciate your contribution.

Comment: Just tried this again.  It worked.  Thank you! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

I set up your files and debugged through the source code.

**Where should the step files be?**

Basically, in `loader.js` [this line](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/4fb5873d63e5c5218091509a3c8a382d8188a1f4/lib/loader.js#L25)

```
const stepDefinitionsToRequire = getStepDefinitionsPaths(filePath)
  .map((sdPath) => `require('${sdPath}')`);
```

returns an empty array with your setup.

Digging into `getStepDefinitionsPaths`, and ignoring common steps for the moment, [this line](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/4fb5873d63e5c5218091509a3c8a382d8188a1f4/lib/getStepDefinitionsPaths.js#L13)

```
let nonGlobalPath = getStepDefinitionPathsFrom(filePath);
```

is responsible for deciding where the steps files come from (filePath is the feature file full path).

and `getStepDefinitionPathsFrom.js` is just

```
return filePath.replace(path.extname(filePath), "")
```

which just removes the extension from

```
.../cypress/integration/examples/BDD/shoppingCart.feature
```

to give

```
.../cypress/integration/examples/BDD/shoppingCart
```

Then on [this line](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/4fb5873d63e5c5218091509a3c8a382d8188a1f4/lib/getStepDefinitionsPaths.js#L26) `nonGlobalPath` is turned into a glob pattern to get all files of type .js, .ts, or .tsx

```
const nonGlobalPattern = `${nonGlobalPath}/**/*.+(js|ts|tsx)`;
```

which gives

```
.../cypress/integration/examples/BDD/shoppingCart/**/*.+(js|ts|tsx)
```

**Conclusion:** the step files must be in a folder with the same name as the feature file (in your case `cypress/integration/examples/BDD/shoppingCart/`) - ***except*** if you modify the `commonPath` setting (see below).

The step definition files can be named anything, as long as they have the correct extension. All files in that folder get searched for step definitions.

**There is no need to move files up into the integration folder**.

### Fix #1

Create a new folder `cypress/integration/examples/BDD/shoppingCart/` and move `shoppingCartStepDef.js` into it.

---

**Config setting**

- `stepDefinitions` by itself has no effect on the steps location, but clearly it should from the documentation. This looks like a bug introduced by some change.
- `nonGlobalStepBaseDir` affects the common steps path (which contains steps used across many features, e.g login), but not the path specific to the shoppingCart feature. Again, a bug due to the above problem.
- `commonPath` seems to work as long as it points directly to the step definitions. The glob pattern `**/*.+(js|ts|tsx)` usage also has a bug - the  pattern omits a trailing `/` which means the `**` part (indicating any subfolder) is ineffective (See the difference between [line 28](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/4fb5873d63e5c5218091509a3c8a382d8188a1f4/lib/getStepDefinitionsPaths.js#L28) and the preceding line 26)

### Fix #2

Set the commonPath config option to the folder containing the step definitions

```
"commonPath": "cypress/integration/examples/BDD/"
```

and you tests will work.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the response. So are you saying this I am having this problem because it looks like my feature and step definition file appear to be in different locations to the the plugin?   However, both feature and step definition  files are in the same folder.  I so am confused why it can't see them.  I'm totally puzzled.    Excuse my  ignorance a number of things went over my head,  can you tell me in the simplest terms possible 'how do I fix this?'

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the length of it. I'll make some mods.

Comment: A side note, because this plugin uses a file preprocessor you will need to restart the Cypress runner between changes to config.

Comment: Also there's a [pull request](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/pull/578) that looks like it will fix the bugs in configuration paths.

Comment: So basically the bug isn't with my coding. It's actually with this version of the plugin - I've uncovered a bug.   Is that right?  So, your doing fix and when I restart my VS studio and run the BDD code again, it should work  this time.   This that right?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood.  So basically, download the updated version of the with the fix and run my test again and it should work.  Is the right?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this issue by doing the following:

I raised a ticket with the Developer as I noticed a NUMBER of people  were all experiencing the same issue.  The developer found they had a bug, fixed it and released a new version.

I had another issue after the new release and was able to fix that by:

I created a new folder  under BDD called shopping cart. so it `integrations/BDD/shoppingCart`

Then I added the following to the package.json

```
 },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
    "stepDefinitions": "cypress/integration/BDD"
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/596](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/596), use a folder matching the feature file

[image]

Comment: thank you.  It's reading the step definition file.  So I can finally move on  from this issue.!!

Answer (score 1):

I think these changes will help. From your error I can tell is that the Feature file is not able to find your step definitions.

1. Change the name of the `integration/examples` to `integration`. Because of what I see from the [cypress pre-processor plugins page](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor#how-to-organize-the-tests), the tests are being searched under `cypress/integration`.
2. Again referring to the [cypress pre-processor plugins page](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor#step-definitions), the recommended way of writing a step definition file is that the steps definitions are searched from a directory with the same name as your `.feature` file.

So in your case, your `.feature` file is at `cypress/integration/BDD/shoppingCart.feature`. Now create a folder by the same name as the feature file inside the BDD folder `cypress/integration/BDD/shoppingCart` and inside that place your step definitions file there.

Comment: both files have the same name, and are written exactly the same.  However, I will double check just to be sure.  Thank you I really appreciate you.

Comment: your `shoppingCartStepDef.js` file should be under `cypress/integration/BDD/shoppingCart`.

Answer (score 0):

If the feature file is unable to read the .js script file then try to add the following in the package.json file.

When you define correct folder hierarchy then it will be able to detect and run the the script in the test runner of cypress. Like i have new folder with name "Drayxchange" so i added it like this below:

```
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
    "stepDefinitions": "cypress/integration/Drayxchange"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code into the package.json file:

```
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
    "stepDefinitions": "filepath"
  },
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: It looks like there are already two of this answer posted!